# htaccess redirect all asset URLs except starting with specific strings

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say the project structure is like this:

```
/
/public/assets/css/<css files go here>
/public/assets/js/<js files go here>
/public/assets/img/<image files go here>
/storage/assets/css/<css files go here>
/storage/assets/js/<js files go here>
/storage/assets/img/<image files go here>
/resources/assets/css/<css files go here>
/resources/assets/js/<js files go here>
/resources/assets/img/<image files go here>
```

I would like to redirect all css and js asset requests to `/public/` except the requests which start with `resources` or `storage`

for example this request: `/assets/css/style.css` has to be redirected to: `/public/assets/css/style.cc`

But, `/storage/assets/css/style.cc` has to stay as it is.

What I am trying is something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^![storage|resources](.*\.css)$ /public/$1  [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^![storage|resources](.*\.js)$ /public/$1  [L,R=302]
```

I know I am missing something in regex.

Does anyone know how to correct it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, very close to a solution but you have to apply your condition inside a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(storage|resources|public)
RewriteRule .*\.(css|js)$ /public/$0  [L,R=302]
```

Otherwise you can go with a one-liner [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) which uses a negative lookahead to apply redirection rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!storage|resources|public).*\.(css|js)$ /public/$0  [L,R=302]
```

Comment: And will happen with images in css or js like bacground-image, etc?

Comment: @step as long as they reside in the same server, and apache handles them, yes.